# Column must appear in the GROUP BY clause

Tags: postgresql

I have this query:

```
SELECT 
"EventReadingListItem"."id"
, "EventReadingListItem"."UserId"
FROM "EventReadingListItems" AS "EventReadingListItem" 
group by "EventReadingListItem"."EventId";
```

When I run it I get the error

```
Column "EventReadingListItem"."id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function.
```

Why? I have read similar questions but I don't really get why this simple group by is not working. Is it because the field in group by is not known as "EventReadingListItem" yet?

Comment: Which value of `"EventReadingListItem"."id"` do you want to select, for each distinct `"EventReadingListItem"."EventId"`? (because there could be multiple & PostgreSQL won't choose one randomly, instead of you)

Comment: any of them. it's not important. should I use max/min?

Comment: well, if it's not that important, why would you like to select any? -- `SELECT min(id), min("UserId")` might select values, which has nothing to do with each other (in other words, there may be no actual row, which has `id = min(id)` **and** `"UserId" = min("UserId")` at the same time) -- you can try `DISTINCT ON`, or some of the solutions from [tag:greatest-n-per-group]

Answer (score 5):

So, according to your comment, this should work for you.

Gives unique rows for each `EventId` which does have smallest/min `id` value:

```
select DISTINCT ON (EventId) EventId, id, UserId
from EventReadingListItems
order by EventId, id
```